# SQlite delete inner join

Tags: sqlite

I have read alot of other answers but cannot get this working!.

```
select * from invTypes
inner join invGroups on invtypes.groupID = invgroups.groupID
where invGroups.categoryID = 25;
```

I simply want to delete the record from invTypes if the category ID matches to 25

Would be very grateful of assistance

I have already tried:

```
delete from invTypes
inner join invGroups on invtypes.groupID = invgroups.groupID
where invGroups.categoryID = 25;
```

Gives error:
near "inner": syntax error:

```
DELETE FROM invTypes
WHERE groupID in ( SELECT groupID FROM invGroups INNER JOIN invTypes ON (invGroups.groupID = invTypes.groupID) 
WHERE invGroups.categoryID = 25);
```

Gives:
ambiguous column name: groupID: DELETE FROM invTypes
WHERE groupID in ( SELECT groupID FROM invGroups INNER JOIN invTypes ON (invGroups.categoryID = invTypes.categoryID) WHERE invGroups.categoryID = 25);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use  `delete` with a `where` clause

```
delete from invTypes
where groupId in ( select groupId from invGroups where CategoryID =25)
```

Comment: Perfect.. I knew I was over complicating it.  Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

```
DELETE invTypes
FROM invTypes
INNER JOIN invGroups
ON invTypes.groupID = invGroups.groupID
WHERE invGroups.categoryID = 25;
```